# Test a specific FormRequest was used in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am **not** looking to test validation against valid/invalid data. What I want to test is that a `FormRequest`'s validation was ***used*** in a request.

```php
// Controller
public function store(MyStoreRequest $request)
{
    // validation should have already happened once before this line.
    SomeModel::create($request->validated());

    return ...;
}
```

```php
// Feature Test Class

// broken
public function test_store_method_uses_validation()
{
    $spy = $this->spy(MyStoreRequest::class);
    $uri = '...';
    $data = [...];   // valid or invalid data, results are the same
    $status = '...';

    $this
        ->postJson($uri, $data)
        ->assertStatus($status) // this breaks the test
    ;

    $spy->shouldHaveReceived('validated')->once();
}
```

This test does not work. The error given is from the query builder.

> `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create()`: Argument #1 (`$attributes`) must be of type `array`, `null` given, called in `/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php` on line 23

---

If I were to remove the assertion against the status, the test works but at this point I'm not sure if it's actually doing what it's supposed to.

```php
// Feature Test Class

// works
public function test_store_method_uses_validation()
{
    $spy = $this->spy(MyStoreRequest::class);

    $this->postJson($uri, $data);

    $spy->shouldHaveReceived('validated')->once();
}
```

Comment: I can't speak for phpUnit, but Pest has a `toBeUsed` assertion. https://pestphp.com/docs/arch-testing#content-tobeused

Comment: I'm not using Pest sadly so I can't test and see if it gives me a different result

Comment: What do you mean by "a FormRequest's validation was used in a request"? If you've type hinted it in the controller, it will be used. This sounds like testing the framework and not testing your code, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @miken32 I realize it's testing the framework, which is why it's not a complex test.

Comment: @IGP totally the other way around, if you want to test the framework, usually it is way more complex, because you have to know how it works and correctly assert and mock everything. What issue did you encounter that you need to achieve this test?

Comment: @matiaslauniti No issues. I just decided to move all the validation testing to its own class (StoreRequestTest) and wanted to leave behind a test that said "StoreRequest is being used to validate everything"

Comment: So now you could say I'm just curious about what it would take for the test to work and why more than -needing- it to work.